# More beautiful, indented, pretty-printing

Tags: ruby, pretty-print, inspect

`Array.inspect` returns its output in a flat line:

```
aoa = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
puts aoa.inspect # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Is there an easy way to get an indented output instead? The exact format  (e.g., whether there is a line break after the first `[`) is not important to me. I just would like to have it more readable.

Compare Perl:

```
  DB<2> print Dumper([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          [
            4,
            5,
            6
          ]
        ];
```

The solution should support hashes as well and handle other things gracefully.

Comment: Those preparing answers will cut and paste your code and then delete all `irb(main):001:0>`. Why not save them the trouble of the second step?

Comment: Thank you, Mladen, for whatever reason I did not find the question you linked. Problem solved.

Comment: You should write "@Miaden", rather than "Miadan", so that SO will notify the person that a comment has been left for them..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try the [AwesomePrint](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) gem which would return the following by default (the actual output is colored) and is customizable:

```
aoa = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
#=> [
#     [0] [
#       [0] 1,
#       [1] 2,
#       [2] 3
#     ],
#     [1] [
#       [0] 4,
#       [1] 5,
#       [2] 6
#     ]
#   ]
```

Comment: I would not install a gem for such a simple, lightweight and already stdlib implemented (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate) function.

Comment: I used to use `puts xxx.inspect` while debugging test code; `ap xxx` now works fine in the Cucumber environment that is quite colored already. Going with this answer, but anyone feel free to check the linked question that this is a duplicat of.

Answer (score -1):

I think `JSON.pretty_generate` is what you are looking for.

```
require 'json'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(["asdf", [1, 2, 3]])
```

outputs:

```
[
  "asdf",
  [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
]
```

and for hashes:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate({a: 1, b: 2, c: {x: 1234}})
```

outputs:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": {
    "x": 1234
  }
}
```

Comment: By doing this, you will lose information. You will lose distinction between string keys and hash keys of a hash. This cannot be a substitute to inspection.

Comment: @sawa Do you really have hashes like `{a: 1, "a" => 2}`?
I thinks it's a good way to pretty print a hash as well as arrays.